# How to use async pipe with function in Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to move execution of a function to a `microtask` so it is executed not in current `task`.

Template:

```
<ion-button 
            color="primary" 
            type="submit" 
            expand="block" 
            fill="solid"
            [disabled]="f.invalid || !datesValid()">Book</ion-button>
```

How do I add `async` pipe so that `!datesValid()` is resolved asynchronously?
Note that `datesValid` returns `Observable<boolean>`.

Comment: Did you tried this ? `[disabled]="f.invalid || (!datesValid() | async)"`

Comment: Yes, I am not sure it is correct.

Comment: And it's not working ?

Comment: It works like this `[disabled]="f.invalid || !(datesValid() | async)"`.

Comment: I don't think that's a bad practise. Actually you function return an observable. I don't know other way to subscribe to it from the `.html` file :)

Answer (score 0):

As a pipe is a function, `async` accepts Observable and returns the latest value it has emitted.
Code `[disabled]="f.invalid || !(datesValid() | async)"` works fine.